# How to format a MySQL query that involves divison

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with a column upvote, and a column downvote, and I only wish to return results that have a specific ratio between the two and the total vote count, say between .4 and .6 I would consider these results to be "controversial" so to speak.

Is it possible to format a MySQL query that involves the divison of two or more rows?

Comment: Surely by *row* you actually mean ***column***?

Comment: Yes, you're right, I mean _column_ My apologies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE (cola / colb > 0.4) AND (cola / colb < 0.6);
```

Comment: I didn't know it could be that simple. Much Obliged